# How to add a viewPager for swiping between fragments without adding an activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, android-viewpager, viewpage

I am developing a Kotlin app and at some point I want to implement viewPager to swipe between fragments. I have one activity to navigate to the rest of the app through the navigation graph. I have not really understood how this swiping should work.

My question is, do I need to implement a new activity as well besides the pageAdapter? And how this activity is going to cooperate with the main one? My app currently has a splash screen, and after that I would like to have the swipe mode between the fragments.

Answer (score 3):

> I want to implement viewPager to swipe between fragments.

nice

> I have one activity to navigate to the rest of the app through the navigation graph.

cool

> do I need to implement a new activity as well besides the pageAdapter?

no

> And how this activity is going to cooperate with the main one?

don't have a second activity, then it doesn't need to "cooperate"

> I would like to have the swipe mode between the fragments.

https://gist.github.com/Zhuinden/c643f03a023a9cbe83fff6c75c948d3b

```
class MyFragmentPagerAdapter(
    private val context: Context,
    fragmentManager: FragmentManager
) : FragmentPagerAdapter(fragmentManager) {
    override fun getCount() = 2

    override fun getItem(position: Int) = when(position) {
        0 -> FirstFragment()
        1 -> SecondFragment()
        else -> throw IllegalStateException("Unexpected position $position")
    }

    override fun getPageTitle(position: Int): CharSequence = when(position) {
        0 -> context.getString(R.string.first)
        1 -> context.getString(R.string.second)
        else -> throw IllegalStateException("Unexpected position $position")
    }
}

class ParentFragment: Fragment() {
    override fun onCreateView(...) = ...

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        val viewPager = view.findViewById(R.id.view_pager)
        viewPager.adapter = MyFragmentPagerAdapter(requireContext(), childFragmentManager)
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager)
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for the reply, but I still don't get this. I have created the pageAdapter like you suggest. Where should the code from the parentFragment be implemented? I am new to this and I am sorry if this sounds like a silly question.

Comment: Also, should I apply the viewPager and tabLayout to all the fragments I wish to swipe?

Comment: You need the ViewPager, you might not need the TabLayout.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

**in your viewPager**

```
 class pageradapter (fm: FragmentManager) : FragmentStatePagerAdapter(fm){
override fun getItem(position: Int): Fragment {
    when(position){
        0-> return fragment1()
        1-> return fragment2() // you can add more if you have more fragments
        else-> return fragment3()

    }
}
override fun getCount(): Int {
    return 3   
 number of fragments that you have so the swiping could work
}
```

**in your fragments 1 or 2 or 3 ...etc**'

```
 class fragment1 : Fragment() {


override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
                          savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment1, container, false)
// write your codes 
}
```

**in your Activity after the splash screen**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(){

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main4)

    val adapter = pageradapter(supportFragmentManager)
    val pager = findViewById<View>(R.id.pager) as ViewPager
    pager.adapter = adapter

}
```